# 3rd party rules

Tags: united-states, legal, international-operating

Why are there 3rd party rules?

http://arrl.org/third-party-operating-agreements lists the countries we are allowed to pass 3rd party messages from.

The fcc regulations specifically state that 3rd party messages must be of a personal or emergency nature.

Why are these rules in place? What is the functional purpose of them? If 2 hams can pass todays baseball game scores to each other why can't we send a similar message on behalf of a 3rd party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amateur Radio Service (ARS) is "for qualified persons of any age who are interested in radio technique solely with a personal aim and without pecuniary interest." ([See FCC website](https://www.fcc.gov/wireless/bureau-divisions/mobility-division/amateur-radio-service#:%7E:text=Millions%20of%20amateur%20operators%20in,telegraphy%2C%20facsimile%2C%20and%20television.))

The ARS is also organized to align with the International Telecommunication Union's (ITU) Radio Regulations (RR) ([See ITU RR Article 25](https://life.itu.int/radioclub/rr/art25.pdf))

One way to ensure that this is maintained is to require that communication is only between licensed parties unless otherwise specified.

There are other services that allow relatively unfettered or business oriented communications on behalf of (or even by) unlicensed entities, it's just that THIS one is specifically organized for amateurs interested in learning, experimenting with, or extending radio technique/technology/etc.

Comment: So, the rules don't have any functional or practical purpose.

Comment: You may have misread the above. It may be that you don't *agree* with the purpose, and that is a perspective you are well within your right to hold! I merely intended to answer the question without endorsing it.

Answer (score 1):

The third party rules, like many other amateur radio rules, are there to protect amateur radio spectrum from commercial users.  The "non pecuniary interest" clause is repeated in several such rules, not just the third party rules.

The thought here is that amateur radio gets use of the spectrum for free.  If it allowed for someone with an amateur radio license to be paid to transmit, then commercial interests could leverage this to get "free" access to the spectrum, crowding us out of our spectrum (perhaps broadcasting music and advertisements) while simultaneously competing with other services (like the phone company and commercial radio stations).

The third party rules are there to allow us to pass message traffic and do things like allow unlicensed operators to talk on the radio while the radio is controlled by a licensed operator, which is great for introducing amateur radio to new people.  The restriction on third party rules is in part to prevent commercial abuse and other abuses.

This might seem silly today, but there is historical precedent for these issues actually being a problem, and date back to 1910 when the regulatory structure for radio spectrum was originally created.  I don't think the need for this regulation is different now than it was then.  (While not directly relevant to this question, prevalence of pirate radio today is evidence for this.)